# Root element not well-formed: extra tag being added on save

Tags: android, xml

I'm totally new to this, and I follow the guide from this page, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I copy their code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when saving this, it automatically creates a new line at the very bottom:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>
```

and it gives me an error message for this specific line. I search forums and the suggestion seems to take the line away, but it is impossible (!). It automatically comes back when saving the file.

Any help out there?